# Generating G-code on android device

Tags: android, arduino, g-code, cnc

Is there any provision or a method to generate the G-code of an image after we capture it from the camera in android phones? I want to control the CNC drawing machine via my android phone but the process is not fully independent since it requires me to generate the G-code on my computer and then transfer it to my phone. 
    Is there any method through which the above could be achieved? I went through Google but I did not find anything healthy. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to map user's actions to that G-code commands and introduce origin point and device scale to it. After that you can represent a sequence of your 'actions' and generate G-code. 
It looks like you should use Visitor design pattern for handling your actions and Builder pattern for generating file with device commands.